Failed to run PX4 SITL simulation with Gazebo Classic: Segmentation fault (core dumped) occurred
I tried to run PX4 SITL simulation with gazebo-classic but get a core dumped error:

I started with gdb and got further information:

It seems that something wrong occurred with Boost.Asio and gzserver. I reinstalled the Boost library and gazebo but it still doesn't work.
I use Ubuntu20.04 and gazebo 11.14.0, and gazebo can run perfectly standalone without px4. The version of Boost library is

Can anyone help solve this issue? Thanks very much!

Please paste any code or console output as code formatted text and not as a screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable, amongst other things...

Sorry, I ran the simulation by command make px4_sitl gazebo, and the console output was .../sitl_run.sh: line 147: 548717 Segmentation fault  (core dumped) gzserver $verbose $world_path $ros_args. I started with gdb and got further information: Thread 53 "gzserver" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. [Switching to Thread 0x7fff31bf8700 (LWP 551511)] boost::asio::detail::reactive_descriptor_service::reactive_descriptor_service (     context=..., this=0x7ffef496bc68)     at /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/reactive_descriptor_service.ipp:39 39   reactor_.init_task();

Please [edit] your question and put any additional details there, and not in the comments. Most of the formatting is lost in the comments and makes it very difficult to read.
